# Painting a transparent object on another transparent object

Tags: java, swing, transparency

I place a semi-transparent JCheckBox object on a semi-transparent JPanel. When I move the mouse cursor over the JCheckBox object, it repaints the JCheckBox object on top of the original JCheckBox object a few cells displaced from the original JCheckBox object.

What I want it to do is to look exactly the same after I move my mouse cursor over it.

Before (the mouse cursor is NOT on the JCheckBox object):

[image: http://i.imgur.com/J6zZwuD.png]

After (the mouse cursor is on the JCheckBox object):

[image: http://i.imgur.com/Wygqq4o.png]

Code:

```
import java.awt.Color;
import java.awt.Graphics;
import javax.swing.JCheckBox;
import javax.swing.JFrame;
import javax.swing.JPanel;

class TransparentPanel extends JPanel{
    public TransparentPanel(){
        super();
        setOpaque(false);
        setBackground(new Color(0, 0, 0, 100));

        JCheckBox checkBox=new JCheckBox("Check Box"){
            protected void paintComponent(Graphics g){
                g.setColor(getBackground());
                g.fillRect(0, 0, getWidth(), getHeight());
                super.paintComponent(g);
            }
        };
        checkBox.setFocusable(false);
        checkBox.setOpaque(false);
        checkBox.setBackground(new Color(200, 200, 200, 50));
        add(checkBox);
    }
    @Override
    protected void paintComponent(Graphics g){
        g.setColor(getBackground());
        g.fillRect(0, 0, getWidth(), getHeight());
        super.paintComponent(g);
    }
    public static void main(String[] args){
        JFrame frame=new JFrame();
        frame.setSize(200, 100);
        frame.setLocationRelativeTo(null);
        frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
        frame.add(new TransparentPanel());
        frame.setVisible(true);
    }
}
```

Sorry if this was already asked. I looked all over and I couldn't find someone with the same problem.
And sorry again if this post isn't a legitimate SSCCE. It's my first post here.

EDIT 1: Edited the code. The problem still exists.

EDIT 2: The code now works.

Comment: If you are going to override the paintComponent() method, then you should do this in your TransparentPanel class since this code will be needed any time you use this component. Also, it should be `super.paintComponent(...)` (without the "s").

Answer (score 2, accepted):

See [Backgrounds With Transparency](http://tips4java.wordpress.com/2009/05/31/backgrounds-with-transparency/) for an explanation on how painting works and maybe a solution you can use.

In this case I would guess you would need to add both TransparentPanel and the checkBox to a separate `AlphaContainer`.

Comment: I added the two parts the link recommends. It still has the repainting problem but the colors are just darker.

Comment: @user2782185, I just finished updating my suggestion. The solution needs to be applied to both components. I tested it with the AlphaContainer.